# Plotting variable importance for CART in R using bar graphs

Tags: r, cart, decision-tree

How can I plot variable importance for a decision tree (CART) in R? Since I am new to R, I need the code (if possible, I want to plot the relative importance score for each variable using bar graphs). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Noel O'Boyle has published some R code that implements variable importance in CART, here:

https://noel.redbrick.dcu.ie/R_classification.html